# Refer to something already known twice

Tags: writing-style, sentence-patterns

I have a technical paper related to computer programming that has the following small section:

> #### Comma-separated expressions
>
> Don't overuse them. Use them where they really make sense.
>
> ```
> FirstName := "John", LastName := "Doe"
> Age := 20
> ```

I don't like the idea to repeat the word "them", but repeating the section heading in the very beginning of its body is not a good one as well.

> #### Comma-separated expressions
>
> Don't overuse comma-separated expressions. Use them where they really make sense.

What's the way to make it less cumbersome?

Comment: It's a little clunky perhaps, but succinct. You may lose clarity with a more complex construction.

Comment: @user888379 Perhaps it is better to combine the sentences? "Use them without overusing"?

Comment: You might want to consider something simpler for the two sentences following the heading: *Use only when necessary.* **Comma-separated expressions** is implied. *Don't overuse* is implied by *Use only when necessary*. *Use only when they make sense* is implied by *Use only when necessary*. Just a thought.

Comment: Or you could just use @RichardKayser's solid advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

> ### Comma-separated expressions
>
> Don't overuse them. Use commas only where they make sense.

On second thought, based on Jim's comment below, this might work better:

> ### Comma-separated expressions
>
> Don't overuse them. Separate expressions with commas only where it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Using commas is different than using comma-separated expressions.

Comment: The title "Comma-separated expressions" provides the necessary context, @Jim

Comment: Ok I like the addition +1